# C++: confusion about accessing class data members while multithreading

Tags: c++, multithreading, class, member

I have the following minimal working example in which I create a number of `markov_chain` objects in a vector `chains` and an equal number of `thread` objects in a vector `workers`, each of which executes a `markov_chain` class member function `sample` on each of the corresponding `markov_chain` objects. This function takes some integer (99 in the below example) and assigns it to the `acceptance` public data member of the `markov_chain` object. I then print the value of `acceptance` for each object in the vector.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>


class markov_chain 
{
public:
    unsigned int length{0}, acceptance{0};

    markov_chain(unsigned int l) {length=l;}
    ~markov_chain() {}

    void sample(int acc);
};

void markov_chain::sample(int acc)
{
    acceptance = acc;
    std::cout << length << ' ' << acceptance << std::endl;
}

int main()  
{
    int number_of_threads{3};
    int number_of_samples{1000};

    std::vector<markov_chain> chains;
    std::vector<std::thread> workers;

    for (int i = 0; i <= number_of_threads; i++) {
        chains.push_back(markov_chain(number_of_samples));
        workers.push_back(std::thread(&markov_chain::sample, chains[i], 99));
    }

    std::for_each(workers.begin(), workers.end(), [](std::thread &t) 
    {
        t.join();
    });

    for (int i = 0; i <= number_of_threads; i++) {
        std::cout << chains[i].length << ' ' << chains[i].acceptance << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Upon executing, the program outputs

```
1000 99
1000 99
1000 99
1000 99
1000 0
1000 0
1000 0
1000 0
```

So the program failed to change the value of `acceptance` for the objects in the vector `chains`. I don't know why this happens; the function `sample` successfully assigns the desired value when I use it without creating threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 problems with your code:

1. when creating each `std::thread`, you are passing a *copy* of each object as the `this` parameter of `sample()`.
2. Pushing multiple objects into the `chains` vector the way you are doing may cause the vector to re-allocate its internal array, thus invaliding any object pointers you have already passed to existing threads, since those original objects are now gone after the re-allocation.

You need to fully initialize the `chains` vector before creating any of the threads.  And you need to pass a *pointer* to each object to each thread.

You can `reserve()` the array up front to avoid re-allocation while pushing into it, eg:

```cpp
int main()  
{
    int number_of_threads{3};
    int number_of_samples{1000};

    std::vector<markov_chain> chains;
    std::vector<std::thread> workers;

    chains.reserve(number_of_threads);

    for (int i = 0; i < number_of_threads; ++i) {
        chains.push_back(markov_chain(number_of_samples));
        workers.push_back(std::thread(&markov_chain::sample, &chains[i], 99));
    }

    for(auto &t : workers) {
        t.join();
    }

    for (auto &c : chains) {
        std::cout << c.length << ' ' << c.acceptance << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/5Uu0Gh)

However, since all of the objects are being initialized with the same starting value, an easier way is to simply get rid of `chains.push_back()` altogether and use `chains.resize()` instead, eg:

```cpp
int main()  
{
    int number_of_threads{3};
    int number_of_samples{1000};

    std::vector<markov_chain> chains;
    std::vector<std::thread> workers;

    chains.resize(number_of_threads, markov_chain(number_of_samples));

    for (int i = 0; i < number_of_threads; ++i) {
        workers.push_back(std::thread(&markov_chain::sample, &chains[i], 99));
    }

    for(auto &t : workers) {
        t.join();
    }

    for (auto &c : chains) {
        std::cout << c.length << ' ' << c.acceptance << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/f7bAOd)

Or, even use the `vector` constructor itself:

```cpp
int main()  
{
    int number_of_threads{3};
    int number_of_samples{1000};

    std::vector<markov_chain> chains(number_of_threads, markov_chain(number_of_samples));
    std::vector<std::thread> workers;

    for (int i = 0; i < number_of_threads; ++i) {
        workers.push_back(std::thread(&markov_chain::sample, &chains[i], 99));
    }

    for(auto &t : workers) {
        t.join();
    }

    for (auto &c : chains) {
        std::cout << c.length << ' ' << c.acceptance << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/4Ha30T)

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong, but each of those three variants still outputs the same wrong result as in my code above, i.e. the value of acceptance remains at 0 instead of 99.

Comment: @Daphne I have updated my answer, as there is another detail I missed earlier. I have also provided a working demo for each of the examples.